# Pattern match inside object in nodejs

Tags: node.js, pattern-matching, json

I have a object like this

```
var obj = {"$match":{"name.first":"aa"}}
```

In nodejs, how can I search for $ pattern inside an object. Any help on this will be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for matches in property names or values as well, and does it have to be recursive? And does the `$` have to be at the start of the string or anywhere? Also does the property/value have to be owned by the object or can it be inherited?

Comment: Its recursive and I have to check for both key and value. $ can be anywhere in the string. The value will be owned by the object

Comment: @cjross I have the answer var text = JSON.stringify(obj);
var n=text.match(/\$/g);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var text = JSON.stringify(obj); var n=text.match(/\$/g);

Answer (score 0):

Short version? you can't, long version? you have to write your own function to do it.\

a *very* simple implementation :

```
var searchObj = function(obj, key, value) {
    if(obj[key] === value) return obj;
    for(var k in obj) {
        var v = obj[k];
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(k) && typeof v === 'object'){
            if(v[key] === value) return v;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to search for $ pattern inside object anywhere not the exact value

Comment: I realize that, but you have to implement it yourself, I gave you a start, you should work from there.